# I am trying to get cgminer on Ubuntu 14.04 and the Guide is troubling me

Tags: cgminer, linux

Okay, I am trying to follow this instruction guide:

http://www.distrogeeks.com/install-cgminer-3-7-2-ubuntu/

and the 20th step did not work because it could not find the server. I downloaded it from AMD themselves except not version 5.0, but version 6.0.

I go up to the 24th step and when I typed that in it said, "cp: target 'ADL_SDK/' is not a directory"

I then installed it and ran it, but then it gave me this message every few seconds or so:

"KnC spi: Can not open SPI device /dev/spidev1.0: No such file or directory.

Please help, I really want to mine some bitcoins and also the similar questions did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you were not in the right directory. Modify this if needed and see if it helps

cp /home/USER/include/* /home/USER/cgminer-3.7.2/ADL_SDK

Just replace USER with your username. If you are running as root (not recommended) then change /home/USER/ to /root/

If that still says directory not found then I don't think you extracted the package from AMD to the right directoy